# Single word for parent who has lost their children (not orphan)

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for parents who have lost their children?

Obviously a child who has lost both parents is an orphan and has been orphaned.

I am struggling to find a word for parents who have lost their children, though.

Comment: I don't think there's such a term. They are just parents who have lost all their children.

Comment: Duplicate on ELL: [...a parent who has lost their child](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19571/a-parentless-child-is-an-orphan-but-the-parents-who-lost-their-child-are/86004#86004)

Comment: I'm surprised I missed the duplicate as I searched quite a bit before. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2):

A parent whose child has died is a **vilomah**

> … I considered that Sanskrit might locate another. And I found "vilomah."
> Vilomah means "against a natural order."
>
> As in, the grey-haired should not bury those with black hair. As in our children should not precede us in death. If they do, we are vilomahed.

Source:
https://today.duke.edu/2009/05/holloway_oped.html

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I like the fact that 'someone' has a word, albeit not in English. I am surprised that the word has not morphed into other languages.

Comment: In Sanskrit “viloma” simply means “inverted” or “contrary to the natural/usual order” (as this answer says) — that is, as it's more common for parents to die before their children, when something happens in the opposite order it is *viloma*. The word is not specific to the death of a child.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend ***BEREAVED*** though it has a general meaning of 'any people who are suffering the death'.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bereaved):

***bereaved***

noun

plural bereaved

: someone who is suffering the death of a loved one

: one who is bereaved

// comfort the bereaved

Comment: *it has a general meaning of ‘any people who are suffering the death.’* is poorly worded, I think you meant any person who has suffered the ‘loss’ of a close friend or relative.

Comment: As you'll be able to tell from looking at the answers posted in the older questions, the term "bereaved" has been supplied a number of times. On EL&U, duplicate answers to duplicate questions is generally not favoured unless that answer contains some original content.

Comment: I agree with Mari-Lou A that the term is too generic and does not directly relate to a parent losing a child.

Comment: I mentioned the general character of the meaning in the answer.